Как опубликовать на github сайт, собранный на webpack?
Хочу опубликовать небольшой проект на GitHub. В локальном депозитарии собрал его с помощью команды npm run build. Далее запускаю команду npm run deploy, чтобы создать дополнительную ветку у себя и в репозитарии GitHub, откуда будет публикация проекта. (Предварительно установил себе в папку проекта npm install gh-pages --save-dev). Однако процесс прерывается и выдает ошибку. Ветка на GitHub не создается. Ошибка такая:
$ npm run deploy


superbox@1.0.0 deploy
gh-pages -d dist

ProcessError: The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
node_modules

hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Пресс-служба\dev\My_PET_Projects\SuperBox\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:42:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5



# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# Compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
/bazel-out

# Node
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# IDEs and editors
.idea/
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
.history/*

# Miscellaneous
/.angular/cache
.sass-cache/
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
testem.log
/typings

# System files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db





Search logs
3s
13s
3s
3s
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv1013_95b8f4 --label 92df29 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_RESULTS_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/SuperBox/SuperBox":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.13
Configuration file: none
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir0 - /github/workspace/docs
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir0 - /github/workspace/docs (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `sass_load_paths'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:114:in `sass_configs'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:119:in `convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:101:in `block in convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `reduce'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:83:in `render_document'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:62:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:479:in `render_regenerated'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:472:in `block in render_pages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:471:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:471:in `render_pages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:192:in `render'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:71:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.10.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-232/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-232/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:25:in `<main>'
Error:  Logging at level: debug GitHub Pages: github-pages v232 GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.10.0 Theme: jekyll-theme-primer Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0 Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages Requiring: jekyll-gist Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata Requiring: jekyll-paginate Requiring: jekyll-relative-links Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter Requiring: jekyll-readme-index Requiring: jekyll-default-layout Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings GitHub Metadata: Initializing... Source: /github/workspace/./docs Destination: /github/workspace/./docs/_site Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental Generating... Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 1.3666e-05 seconds. Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 6.112e-06 seconds. Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 3.236e-06 seconds. Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 2.3935e-05 seconds. Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 1.102e-05 seconds. Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 6.773e-06 seconds. Rendering: assets/css/style.scss Pre-Render Hooks: assets/css/style.scss Rendering Markup: assets/css/style.scss github-pages 232 | Error: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir0 - /github/workspace/docs >


Судя по тексту ошибки нужно убрать /node_modules из .gitignore или выполнить git config advice.addIgnoredFile false. Не понятно, как это мешает собирать статический сайт, но все же попробуйте.

Спасибо, git config помог! Но вылезла новая проблемка уже на гитхабе ((

Нужно в сам build (который с красным крестом) зайти, и посмотреть что там пишет.

Вот , правда я уже не очень понимаю ((

Нашел причину. Я в настройках Build and deployment изначально сам поставил /doc вместо /roots!
